# Compare grid predictions

Tags: predictive-models, prediction

I am interested in methods to compare "predictions" of an inhomogeneous Poisson process, against "sparse" data.

The model I have is that of [inhomogeneous Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Inhomogeneous_Poisson_point_process), say on the unit square $[0,1]^2$, with intensity function $I(x,y)$.  We can factor $I$ as $I(x,y) = \mu f(x,y)$ where $\mu$ is the overall rate of the process (which I am not so interested in) and $f$ is a probability density.

I have various methods which produce a finite probability distribution in the form of a grid / matrix of size $N\times M$ say.  The value in cell $(i,j)$ is meant to be an estimate of the integral of $f$ over that cell.

I then wish to "score" these predictions against a realisation of the process, say points $(x_i, y_i)_{i=1}^n$.  Typically $n$ is small, much smaller than $NM$.

I don't really know how to go about this:

- Should I bin points, assigning $(x_i, y_i)$ to the cell it occurs in?  That would seem to lose information for an event which occurs near the boundary of a cell.
- I could take a Bayesian approach, perhaps, and compute Bayes Factors.  This is the same as computing likelihoods in this case.  This doesn't seem to take much account of the geometry of the problem.